# Changing a CSS class depending on text wrap and window width (Jquery or JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, vertical-alignment

I have a responsive design with some text columns. The columns have h2 headings and floated to the left of the headings are image icons - nicely vertically centered to the heading text. The problem occurs when I narrow the window width. When the single heading lines wrap, they are no longer vertically aligned to the icons.

Basically, I'm trying to write a script that tells the class of the heading to change when it wraps to two lines so that I can alter the vertical position of it to be centered.

I'm really new to scripting so I'm not sure how to write it but this is essentially it:

```
if window width > 768 and if lines of text in #services h2 = 1

#services h2 {
top:9px;
}

else

if window width > 768 and if lines of text in #services h2 > 1

#services h2 {
top:1px;
}
```

Could someone help me properly format this? I'm already using jQuery for some other stuff so if it's possible to do it with that, that would be great.

Thanks!

**EDIT:** The most important part of this is the changing of a class property when a line wraps from 1 line to 2. This is the critical part:

```
if lines of text in #services h2 = 1

#services h2 {
top:9px;
}

else

if lines of text in #services h2 > 1

#services h2 {
top:1px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could  you not just set the vertical position of background image to be 50%? Rather than adding  js to a relatively minor cosmetic change.

Comment: matpol it's not a background image - it's floated to the left of the h2.

Comment: position it absolutely? same idea set the vertical position to 50%

Comment: you would need something around the h2 that has position relative.

Comment: right now I just have:<header> </header> around both the image and the h2.

Answer (score 0):

No JavaScript (includes jQuery) needed, use pure CSS: http://www.css3.info/preview/media-queries/.

A longer explanation can be found at http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: Bergi - Thanks but I know how to use media queries but unless I'm wrong, I can't change a class when text wraps using media queries. That's what I'm primarily trying to do - change the alignment of an element based on how many lines of text there are. The javascript to detect the window width is in addition to the media queries I'm using because I don't want any of the script changes to take effect when the window is below 768 - make sense?

Comment: In defense of @Bergi it sounds like media queries are the right way to do this. I'm really not seeing why you should use JS!

Comment: Ah OK. Counting lines with JS is not a good idea, I think. You could do it with computedvalues of height and lineheight and fontsize, yes, but it will get nasty. Have you tried a table layout (no kidding), that seems to fit your requirement best?

Comment: Bergi - Funny you should mention that! I just found this article: http://css-tricks.com/vertically-center-multi-lined-text/ Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about the 'and if lines of text' but the left side of the AND, would be:

-EDIT- I see, let see if this is what you want.

```
$(window).resize(function(){
     var h =$('#services h2').css('line-height');
     var size = $(window).width();
     if (size > 768){
          if( $('#services h2').height() == h){
                 $('#services h2').css('top','1px')
          }
     }else{
           if( $('#services h2').height() > 2*h){
                 $('#services h2').css('top','9px')
          }
     }

});
```

Comment: if you can show the code win a jsfiddle.net or something it would be easeir to understand

Comment: Thanks Toni. I saw somewhere else that you could detect the height of a container with Javascript and that when text wraps to 2 lines, it obviously changes the height. Maybe that's an approach?

Comment: Also, I could use jsfiddle but what I wrote is hardly code. :)

Comment: @SeanTubridy i meant the HTML